# Can I transfer the warranty of an item to someone else when selling via craigslist?

Tags: selling, used-goods, extended-warranty

I want to sell a used item via craigslist. The item (it's an iRobot Roomba cleaning robot) is very new and in full working condition and I am the first owner. I bought this item in an online shop. It is still under warranty.

When I sell the item to someone else, can she use the warranty? There doesn't seem to be any warranty documents as such, in my understadning the receipt is the warranty, or rather, warranty procedures are dealt with through the online shop where I originally bought the item. I guess if warranty issues need to be resolved the item needs to be returned to the online shop, and they want to see receipt and/or credit card receipt and/or online credentials. These are things I do not want to share with a third party. Also I do not want the hassle of helping the buyer resolve warranty issues if any should arise down the line. I just want to sell the item and never hear about it again.

Can I somehow transfer the warranty to the buyer from craigslist, *without* sharing my account info at that online shop and *without* having to deal with this process anymore? Or, should I just sell the item "as is" without any warranty or guarantees?

[I hope my question is not off-topic]

Comment: Check your warranty statement, some have the clause "Warranty cannot be transferred".

Comment: Seems like a legal question more than a money question.

Comment: Consider migrating to http://law.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about US law, I just did a quick search on the net.

From [store.irobot.com](http://store.irobot.com/helpdesk/index.jsp?display=returns&subdisplay=prodw&MobileOptOut=1)

> **Is the limited warranty transferable with proof of purchase?**
>
> No, the iRobot limited warranty is not transferable. Once you register
>   your robot, you are the only one who can request limited warranty
>   service for the length of the limited warranty.

(Er.. How much more customer-unfriendly can you get? This type of exclusion would be invalid in most of Europe.)

I don't know if in the US there is a separate warranty that needs to be honoured by the seller directly (in your case the online shop you bought it from). If not, then it looks like you should really sell it "as is".